# How to use in Java big double numbers?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, pi

I've found a solution for calculating number of Pi by using BBS algorithm. But I encountered a problem. I'm missing a precision if using a double variable. Is there any suggestion to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
public class Pi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            int a0 = (int) Math.pow(16, k);

            double a1 = (double) 4 / (8 * k + 1);
            double a2 = (double) 2 / (8 * k + 4);
            double a3 = (double) 1 / (8 * k + 5);
            double a4 = (double) 1 / (8 * k + 6);

            double a5 = a1 - a2 - a3 - a4;
            double a6 = (double) 1 / a0;
            double elem = a5 * a6;

            System.out.println(new BigDecimal(elem));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged your question 'bigdecimal'. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the precision of `BigDecimal`, you need to use it for all calculations. It is not sufficient to convert the result from `double` to `BigDecimal` at the end, because the precision is gone by then.

You need to convert all your `aX` variables to `BigDecimal`, and replace operators with calls to the corresponding methods of `BigDecimal` class:

```
BigDecimal pi = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    BigDecimal a0 = new BigDecimal(16).pow(k);
    BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal(4).divide(new BigDecimal(8*k+1), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal a2 = new BigDecimal(2).divide(new BigDecimal(8*k+4), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal a3 = new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(8*k+5), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal a4 = new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(8*k+6), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal a5 = a1.subtract(a2).subtract(a3).subtract(a4);
    BigDecimal a6 = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(a0, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    pi.add(a5.multiply(a6));
    System.out.println(pi);
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/AvTj20).

Comment: @Alex I fixed the runtime error, and added the code missing from your algorithm to accumulate the data into the final number of pi. I picked a random precision of 20; you can change it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using doubles during the calculation itself, thus inevitably losing accuracy. Yes, you're using `BigDecimal` at the end, but only after already destroying data by putting it in doubles.

The solution is to not use doubles at ANY point in the calculation. Use `BigDecimal` for every step of the way.

To use a metaphor: What you're doing is trying to pour a swimming pool's amount of water into a glass, then pouring the glass into the pool and expecting it to be filled. No, it won't be, because most of the water didn't fit in the glass and just poured onto the ground.